# Titanium mobile development - Android resource linking

Tags: titanium

Had someone develop an app in Titanium and had to make a small change to it as well as
update target sdk version to 30 from 28 to get it uploaded to the play store.
After installing all the android SDK's etc I now get an error building the project (see below).

```
[INFO]   [GRADLE] > Task :app:mergeReleaseShaders
[INFO]   [GRADLE] > Task :app:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
[INFO]   [GRADLE] > Task :app:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
[INFO]   [GRADLE] > Task :lib.firebase.cloudmessaging:mergeReleaseShaders
[INFO]   [GRADLE] > Task :lib.firebase.cloudmessaging:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
[INFO]   [GRADLE] > Task :lib.firebase.cloudmessaging:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
[INFO]   [GRADLE] > Task :lib.firebase.cloudmessaging:packageReleaseAssets
[INFO]   [GRADLE] > Task :lib.firebase.core:mergeReleaseShaders
[INFO]   [GRADLE] > Task :lib.firebase.core:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
[INFO]   [GRADLE] > Task :lib.firebase.core:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
[INFO]   [GRADLE] > Task :lib.firebase.core:packageReleaseAssets
[INFO]   [GRADLE] > Task :lib.firebase.core:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly
[INFO]   [GRADLE] > Task :app:mergeReleaseAssets
[INFO]   [GRADLE] > Task :app:compressReleaseAssets
[INFO]   [GRADLE] > Task :app:processReleaseResources FAILED
[INFO]   [GRADLE] > Task :app:mergeReleaseNativeLibs
[ERROR]  [GRADLE] 
[ERROR]  [GRADLE] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[ERROR]  [GRADLE] 
[ERROR]  [GRADLE] * What went wrong:
[ERROR]  [GRADLE] Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.
[ERROR]  [GRADLE] > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
[ERROR]  **[GRADLE]**    > Android resource linking failed
**[ERROR]  [GRADLE]      ERROR:C:\Users\Darren\Documents\Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace\computime-rollcall\build\android\app\build\intermediates\packaged_manifests\release\AndroidManifest.xml:70: AAPT: error: resource string/oss_license_title (aka com.computimeuk.rollcall:string/oss_license_title) not found.**
[ERROR]  [GRADLE]          
[ERROR]  [GRADLE]
```

Comment: Check the error message it is looking for a string `oss_license_title`.
It would also be nice if you could add your Ti SDK version as you normally don't need to set the target to 30 (the current SDK will use 31)

Comment: oh, and if you use firebase push make sure to use the latest version (same for ti.playervices)

Comment: off-topic: Appcelerator Titanium is now discontinued; I'm not sure when you had this app developed but that framework has been dead for years. Not to speak of the incredible amount of bugs and issues their bugtracker had (3k+ iirc). So goodluck maintaining any of that :)

Comment: no really true. It's just handed over to Tidev to maintain it. It was open source before and now even more parts are open. Just the "commercial" parts are removed. Maintaining multiple bigger apps without any issues for years now and will continue to do it. But my opinion is a bit biased since I'm an active user but I wouldn't change the framework